# Adding new sets of key and value from array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

im not yet expert in javascript but I wanted to add a new property in an array of objects with different values which is in an array format.

```
const mainArray = [{name: 'John', age: 30}, {name: 'Jane', age: 25}]

const country = ['Germany', 'Japan']

const res = mainArray.map(x => {
    return {
        name: x.name,
        age: x.age,
        country: country
    }
})
```

i tried this but its not working

expected to be like this

```js
result = [{name: 'John', age: 30, country: 'Germany'}, {name: 'Jane', age: 25, country: 'Japan'}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from your sample code, you actually setting the value of country with the whole array. you should use index

```
const mainArray = [{name: 'John', age: 30}, {name: 'Jane', age: 25}];
const country = ['Germany', 'Japan']

function addKey(arr, key, value) => {
  const res = arr.map((x, index) => {
    return {
      ...x,
      [key]: value[index]
    };
  });
  return res;
};

console.log(addKey(mainArray, 'country', country))
```

from here, you can add any other specific property in the second arg

hope this help you

Answer (score 1):

```
You need to use index variable to access the values from other array
```

```js
const mainArray = [{name: 'John', age: 30}, {name: 'Jane', age: 25}];
const country = ['Germany', 'Japan']

const res = mainArray.map((x,i) => {
    return {
        name: x.name,
        age: x.age,
        country: country[i] // <-- i added [i]
    }
})
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the index of the `country` element is meant to be related to the index of `mainArray`, you can use the overload of `.map` with the `index` parameter,

**modified:** to account for `country` array not containing enough elements to match with your `mainArray`:

```js
const mainArray = [{name: 'John', age: 30}, {name: 'Jane', age: 25}]
const country = ['Germany', 'Japan']

//use the overload of .map with the index, so you can set the new
//property to the value of the country array via the index parameter
const res = mainArray.map((x, index) => {
        return {
            name: x.name,
            age: x.age,
            country: country[index] || 'unknown'
        }
});

console.log(res);
```